# Аналитически оценить временную ассимптотическую сложность функции

Tags: алгоритм, функции, сложность

[image: Функция и доп. условия]

Нужно аналитически вычислить временную асимптотическую сложность алгоритма. Пытался, но не понимаю что делать с условиями, подключать теорию вероятностей?

Comment: Рассматривать самый плохой случай.

Comment: Это основы основ. Вот тут всё, что вам нужно знать о реккурентных отношениях. [Основная теорема о рекуррентных соотношениях](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85)

Answer (score 1):

Если применить [вариант 3](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85#%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82_3), то получается O(N).

Можно и без него:

```
T(N) = AN+T(N/2) = AN + AN/2 +T(N/4) = AN + AN/2 + AN/4 + T(N/8 ) = ...
     = AN(1+1/2+1/4+...) = 2AN
```

то есть O(N).